# Query with DLookup for date between two dates in the refererence table

Tags: ms-access

I have a table that defines date ranges:

```
Reference_table:

[refID] , [start] , [end]
1       1/1/2020      3/3/2020
2       4/3/2020      7/6/2020
3       8/6/2020      10/10/2020
```

and another that has date column

```
Incident_table:

[IncidentID] , [incident_date]
56       1/2/2020
57       8/3/2020
58       12/5/2020
```

Now I'd like to define a Query, that gives me the reference_id to every Incident.
I tried to use

```
SELECT Reference_table.refID, Incident_table.IncidentID
FROM Reference_table
INNER JOIN Incident_table
ON (Reference_table.end >= Incident_table.incident_date >= Reference_table.begin);
```

which gave me an empty dataset

and with a lookup

```
SELECT 
    IncidentID,
    DLookup("refID";"Reference_table";"[start]<= #" & Incident_date & "# <= [end]") as reference
FROM Incident_table
```

Which gave me all the records, but reference was #Error (instead of 1..3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a good ol' *where-join*:

```sql
SELECT 
    Reference_table.refID, 
    Incident_table.IncidentID
FROM 
    Reference_table,
    Incident_table
WHERE
    incident_date Between Reference_table.begin And Reference_table.end
```

Comment: Awesome. I'm using access with SQL for more than 30 years (on and off) now. And I never got around to that. A bit counterintuitive to me, but works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the DLookup was the right way, but different language versions of access throw you off the right path. For reference, a working solution is:

```
SELECT 
  IncidentID,
  DLookup(
     "refID",
     "Reference_table",
     "[start]<= #" & 
        Format([Incident_date],"mm\/dd\/yyyy") & 
     "# between [start] and [end]") & 
     "# <= [end]"
   ) as reference
FROM Incident_table
```